# Inserts wrong value to MySQL table

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, insert

I have dynamic list from MySQL table on my php page so that HTML part below is 10-20 times per page. If I click that submit-button it does insert stuff to my database but player_id is always the id of the first record on page. I need to be able to click one in the middle for example and insert that correct value to mysql table. Can someone point me to right direction on how to achieve this? Thanks!

**HTML part:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="player_id" value="<?php echo $player_id;?>">
<input name="insert" type="submit" class="button" value="3">
```

**JS part:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('[name=insert]').click(function(){
    var player_id=$("[name=player_id]").val();

    $.post('process.php', {player_id: player_id, points: 3},
function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").fadeIn(1500); 
});
return false;
});
    });
```

**PHP/MySQL part (process.php):**

```
  **Connection stuff here
   $player_id=$_POST['player_id'];
   $points=$_POST['points'];
   $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO p_points (player_id,points) VALUES('$player_id','$points')");
```

And before anyone says, yes I will change to PDO :) But I just want to make this work correctly first, after that I can learn PDO properly.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your form?

Comment: In your process.php script have you checked what data is being sent? That way we can figure out if it's a problem with the javascript or the PHP / MySQL.

Comment: Tomanow: There is not much more in the form.. Just those submit-button next to player's name and that hidden field containing player_id.

Comment: Keeleon: Well that's kind of my whole process.php at the moment.. Should I do something more in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    var player_id = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(player_id);
$.post('process.php', {player_id: player_id, points: 3},
function(data){
    $("#message").html(data);
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").fadeIn(1500); 
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ySBAm/

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. Instead of the first value it now inserts just 0.

Comment: No problem :) But this doesn't do the trick either. So this does insert player_id but it's always the first id on the list. So still same issue